# Why File Server is not accessible when the DNS/DC is down?

Tags: windows-server-2008

The domain controller is in another(Mumbai)city and file sever is in another (Pune) city. When the Mumbai's link is down then the file server is also not accessible for Pune users. It gives the error like :

Server is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the
 administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
 There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.

When the link is up then no problem.
I want to access the file share server when the link(DNS) is down .
Please help....

Comment: You might want to read [this post on domain controllers](http://serverfault.com/questions/472127/number-of-domain-controllers-needed)

Answer (score 3):

The file server needs to access the domain controller in order to determine whether it is allowed to give access to the resources under its management. To make more resilient, you may want to add a replica domain controller in Pune.